# OAuth User Credentials Granting

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm using the [oauth2-server-php](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php) module in which you can use the `grant=password` credential type where it's necessary to use username, password and client_id at least.

But in the [description](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.1) it is stated that you only have to use a Username and Password to ask for a token and, in case you are using a confidential client or you pass a clientId (doesn't say anything about being required) you have to send a clientId.

I have understanded wrongfuly the standard in this case and it's really required the use of a clientId or in this case it's not really required and using only a:

```
curl https://example.com/token -d 'grant_type=password&username=my_name&password=my_password
```

Would be enough?

Comment: Have you tried without a client id? Anyway, if the Github API documentation says they require a client id, they probably do so. What is the problem? Can't you just request a client id form github and use it?

Comment: No, I'm not using the Github Oauth system, the link directs to a OAuth server developed for php.

Comment: OK, that was confusing, I fixed the link.Nonetheless, if their documentation says they require a client id, they probably do so.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the security policy decided by your authorization server.
In your case, it seems that it refuses non authenticated clients as many other servers do.
The fact that your client must be authenticated, even if it is a public client, is absolutely normal. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3

Moreover, the example in the RFC clearly indicates the client is authenticated (see Authorization header).

Comment: I have contacted the developer of that module and he says the same; it's possible to make a non client login standard, but they prefer not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Confidential clients are clients that authenticate themselves to the Authorization Server, public clients by definition do not. Regarding the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow, the standard allows for all of:

- a confidential client that uses client authentication and thus
  providing a `client_id`
- a public client providing a `client_id`
- a public client not providing a `client_id`

Authorization servers may support any combination of the above. Even though it is recommended to use the `client_id`, security-wise it does not add much since it is not a secret and may be guessable or retrievable otherwise.

On the average it is common for Authorization Servers to require it for logging/analysis purposes.